# Is this the correct way to do a scheduled script on a sales order based on a search against vendor invoice?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Goal: To update a checkbox on a sales order whenever a vendor invoice for FedEx is entered.

Sales Order Fields Involved:

- Carrier - This is a list of all vendors that the user populates depending on what vendor is being used for the sales order.
- FedEx Invoice Received - This is a checkbox that needs to be checked whenever a vendor invoice for FedEx is entered.

Vendor Invoice Fields Involved:

- Vendor
- Sales Order - This is a list of all sales order where the user would select the sales order that corresponds with the invoice that is being entered.

My plan is to do this as a scheduled script but am struggling on how to properly set this up.

My initial thought is to do the following:

- Create a search in the script that finds any vendor invoices where the carrier is FedEx
- Have the search columns result be the sales order field that the user selects
- In a forEach loop do the following:
- Have var salesorderid = the result from the search column
- Inside the loop use record.load to load the sales order and use the variable salesorderid as the id
- Set value for the carrier invoices received checkbox in each sales order found
- save the sales order

Is this the optimal way of doing this? I feel there may be a better way of doing this but am not sure how. I did try via a mass update but that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your approach and it sounds viable. You could do this with a Map/Reduce script to do the processing of each sales order in parallel, but if there aren't a lot of sales orders to update, you're better off with the Scheduled Script.

I would use `record.submitFields` instead of `record.load` on the sales order as you're only writing to one field.

Keep in mind that User Event scripts will trigger for the sales order.